# Trouble with Ace code editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have successfully created an Ace editor before, but recently I am making a website called CodeProjects, and I want to put an Ace editor in. Whenever I try, it only shows the text `function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
}`. On the page http://ace.c9.io/#nav=embedding&api=ace, it says you only need the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>ACE in Action</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #editor { 
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor">function foo(items) {
            var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
            return x;
            }
        </div>
        <script src="/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script>
            var editor = ace.edit("editor");
            editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
            editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
        </script>
    </body>
```

but when I try to embed it (or even just make the editor, not the site), again, it only shows `function foo(items) { var x = "All this is syntax highlighted"; return x; }`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

it also says to copy files into your project. If you don't want to do that, include script from cdn

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/ace/1.1.01/min/ace.js"
             type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

see http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/165/edit

Comment: Do you use ie8? in that case try putting code in pre instead of div http://jsbin.com/ojijeb/172/edit

Comment: Ok, your question doesn't give enough information to see what's wrong on your site. It works fine on jsbin so the problem is somewhere on your site.

Comment: I was kinda sick of coding so I used Weebly to make my site. I tried using the Embed Code option to use it, but when I add `height: 500px`, It still only shows as one line.

Comment: Maybe I should put it in an iFrame?

Comment: If you can't figure out what is the problem, maybe you should at least show the page demonstrating it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34408/discussion-between-jjp-and-a-user)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the content **outside** of the editor div [or fetch the content on page load using AJAX]. Either way, you then load the content into the editor with JavaScript: `editor.setValue("hello world");`.

To set the height of the editor, you resize the div it lives in, then call the editor's resize method.

```
var div = document.getElementById('editor');    
div.style.height = some_multiple_of_the_line_height_for_tidiness;
editor.resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you need to change div to pre. Just using pre instead of div in following way should solve your problem.

```
<pre id="editor" >
</pre>
```